# Exact string search in array

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I have an array like:

```
moduleList=(AB, ABCdef, ABCd)
```

My array is numerically-indexed array not an associative array. I want to do an exact match for each element in array and to perform certain tasks.

Currently I'm doing like:

```
if [[  ${moduleList["AB"]}  ]]; then
    #do this.
fi



if [[  ${moduleList["ABCdef"]}  ]]; then
    #do that.
fi
```

But both the conditions are getting true as `"AB"` is there in each word. How can I distinguish each condition based on an exact match.

Comment: @steeldriver, they evaluate to the value of the named variable, _recursively_. Try `x=y; y=1; echo $((x))` (or even `x=y; y=x; echo $((x))`, which does give an error).

Comment: @ilkkachu or in a better example (which I think I've first seen in a post from Stéphane Chazelas): `x='q[$(cat /etc/passwd >/dev/tty)]'; AB=x; echo "$AB ${moduleList["AB"]}"`

Comment: @mosvy, yeah, the thing with indexes and expansions is the next one up.

Answer (score 1):

`${moduleList["AB"]}` or the same without the quotes takes the value of a variable called `AB`, and uses that as the index. If that variable is not set, the value you get is zero, and that expands to `AB`, the zeroth item of the array. That's a non-empty string, so it's truthy.

> But both the conditions are getting true as "AB" is there in each word.

This, quite simply, is not the reason. You'd get the same with `${moduleList["x"]}`, or whatever. Or, if the named variable *is* set to a number, you get the appropriate item in the array:

```
$ moduleList=(AB, ABCdef, ABCd)
$ unset x
$ echo "${moduleList[x]}"
AB,
$ x=2
$ echo ${moduleList["x"]}
ABCd
```

You'll have to loop over the array to find if a matching string exists, or change into an associative array and use the strings in as keys.

Also note that you probably don't want the commas in the assignment, you get literal commas in the values, as seen above.

Comment: @BiswajitMaharana Instead of looping over the array, something like this may do `case " ${moduleList[@]} " in *" AB "*) ... do if val found ;; esac`

Comment: @mosvy I can't use switch case as I have to check each element in array and do the logic.

Comment: You can perfectly replace the code _you_ posted with `case ... esac`s as in my example. If you had something else in mind, you should've posted _that_.

Comment: @mosvy case ... esac works like if ... elif. But what I need is multiple if .. if statement so that each condition should be validated

Comment: Use multiple `case ... esac` ;-) Either the array is small and it doesn't matter, or the array is large, and then it's much faster than a loop.

Comment: Instead of `case...esac`, you can also use `[[ " ${a[@]} " = *" AB "* ]]`

Comment: Thanks, the latest suggestion worked for my case.